# Need slider that can increment exponentially (not using range)

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, slider

At the moment I am using jQuery UI's slider to allow people to select a donation amount. The problem is, the slider is to small and needs to compensate for the minimum of $1 and the maximum of $10,000. The proposed solution is to use a small increment, maybe $1 or $2, for values between $1 - $1000, and then from there, raising the increment exponentially all the way to $10,000, but I can't find a plugin capable of this.

So right now I have the increment at $1 and as you probably guessed, its nearly possible to select a specific money amount.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Is there some benefit to having a slider like this vs. a text box where the amount can be typed in?  As a user, I wouldn't take the time to fiddle with a slider if I could just type it in.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logarithmic slider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846221/logarithmic-slider)

Comment: You might also be interested in: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/non-linear-logarithmic-or-exponential-scale-for-slider

Comment: @Yi Jiang: I'm not convinced that the answers to "Logarithmic slider" really capture the whole picture.

Answer (score 1):

A slider hardly strikes me as the right tool for that job.

But if you insist, you could increase the slider step size (say, 10 possible positions) and for each step lookup the amount it corresponds to.

Example:

- 1 -> 1$
- 2 -> 2$
- 3 -> 5$
- 4 -> 10$
- 5 -> 50$
- 6 -> 200$
- 7 -> 1k$
- 8 -> 5k$
- 9 -> 10k$
- 10 -> 20k$

Comment: That does sound like the right mapping for a donation application. (And it's not exactly exponential, so you'd want to use a lookup table of some sort.)

Answer (score 1):

To add to [@brunodecarvalho](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943307/need-slider-that-can-increment-exponentially-not-using-range/3943361#3943361)'s answer, make a `JSlider` with tick marks but no labels, couple it with a `JLabel` or a `JTextField` so that when the slider's value is changed, the appropriately mapped value appears in the `JLabel` or `JTextField`.

If you're using a `JTextField`, trust the value in the `JTextField` as the user's actual donation amount (so that he can edit it and pick a value that's not on the slider), and update the slider to an appropriately close tick mark when the `JTextField` changes.

Comment: Ok, so I gave this answer in Java class names, becuase of the java tag, but now I'm convinced the java tag is wrong. I'm not deleting the answer, because anyone with a sufficiently general computing knowledge should be able to translate the class names into the language/toolkit of their choice.

Answer (score 0):

As has been said before, you will have to map the slider positions to money amounts. Here is a nice almost-logarithmic mapping that has the nice property of giving round values:

```
var slider_values = [];
var mantissas = [1, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
for (var base = 1; base < 10000; base *= 10) {
    for (var i = 0; i < mantissas.length; i++)
        slider_values.push(mantissas[i] * base);
}
slider_values.push(10000);
```

This maps the integer range [0..64] to the range 1 - 10,000.