# Use UISider to generate a logarithmic scale of values

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uislider, logarithm

Is there a way to got the values outputted by a UISlider in an iPhone app to increase exponentially? For example the first third generate 1 -10, the second third generate 11 to 100, and the final third generate 101 to 1000?

Comment: That sounds more like exponential than logarithmic...

Comment: i wasn't sure it was the right word but wikipedia says "A simple example is when increments on the vertical axis of a chart are labeled 1, 10, 100, 1000, instead of 1, 2, 3, 4."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can compute yourself the log/exp value from the slider, and display this value !

But if you want a value between 1 to 1000, you can set min of the slider to 0, max to 3 and make the power of 10:

```
powf(10.0,mySlider.value)
```

Comment: haha kinda genius, didn't think of that :P
what's the obj-c code for this? is there a function or do i write the math myself?
use if statements to determine how much to multiply each value by, or is there a cleaner way?

Comment: That is the function, in C. Wherever you want to retrieve the slider value as exponential, use that snippet there. Don't forget to mark Benôit's answer as accepted.

Comment: Note: For 0->1 log10 you should do something like `((10^x)-1)/9`. I found with volume for example, a sliderValue from 0.0 to 1.0 correlates best with log base 100: `float volumeLevel = (powf(100.0f, sliderValue)-1.0f)/99.0f;`

Answer (score 13):

I derived these Objective C methods from this post: [Logarithmic slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846221/logarithmic-slider?tab=oldest#tab-top)

```
-(double) wpmForSliderValue: (double) sliderValue {
    // Input will be between min and max
    static double min = WPM_SLIDER_MIN;
    static double max = WPM_SLIDER_MAX;

    // Output will be between minv and maxv
    double minv = log(WPM_SCALE_MIN);
    double maxv = log(WPM_SCALE_MAX);

    // Adjustment factor
    double scale = (maxv - minv) / (max - min);

    return exp(minv + (scale * (sliderValue - min)));
}

-(double) sliderValueForWpm: (double) wpm {
    // Output will be between min and max
    static double min = WPM_SLIDER_MIN;
    static double max = WPM_SLIDER_MAX;

    // Input will be between minv and maxv
    double minv = log(WPM_SCALE_MIN);
    double maxv = log(WPM_SCALE_MAX);

    // Adjustment factor
    double scale = (maxv - minv) / (max - min);

    return (((log(wpm) - minv) / scale) + min);
}
```

Comment: I needed to work out how to adjust an aspect ratio from something arbitrary down to 1:1 based on a value of 1.0-.0.5, this code was the basis for my solution. Thank you!

Comment: Exactly what I needed!