# logarithmic slider returns NaN

Tags: javascript, algorithm, slider, logarithm

I'm trying to follow the example at [Logarithmic slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846221/logarithmic-slider).

Here's the code I'm using:

```
Timeline._MIN_PER_MINUTE = 1;
Timeline._MIN_PER_HOUR = Timeline._MIN_PER_MINUTE * 60.0;
Timeline._MIN_PER_DAY = Timeline._MIN_PER_HOUR * 24.0;
Timeline._MIN_PER_WEEK = Timeline._MIN_PER_DAY * 7.0;
Timeline._MIN_PER_MONTH = Timeline._MIN_PER_WEEK * 4.0;
Timeline._MIN_PER_YEAR = Timeline._MIN_PER_MONTH * 12.0;

var scale_down = 0.00001;
var scale_up = 100000;
Timeline._SLIDER_MIN = 0;
Timeline._SlIDER_MAX = 100;
Timeline._SLIDER_STEP = 1;

Timeline._scale = function (value) {
  var minIn = Timeline._SLIDER_MIN;
  var maxIn = Timeline._SLIDER_MAX;

  var minOut = Math.log(Timeline._MIN_PER_MINUTE);
  var maxOut = Math.log(Timeline._MIN_PER_YEAR);

  var scale = (maxOut - minOut) / (maxIn - minIn);

  return Math.exp(minOut + scale * (value - minIn));
};

Timeline._sliderChangedHandler = function(id){
  var val = Timeline._scale($('#scale_slider' + id).val());
  alert(val);
};
```

For some reason I get NaN as a result.
Does someone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this 
var val = Timeline._scale(parseInt($('#scale_slider' + id).val(), 10));

Comment: alert($('#scale_slider' + id).val()) and see what value you get

Comment: shankhan, I get values ranging from 0 to 100.

Comment: I got it you are defining SlIDER_MAX  and using SLIDER_MAX (notice capital L)